# Rails change locale get back to current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following rails code:

I try to set the language of my application with this

```
 def changelocale
if Settings.language_supported?(params[:locale])
  session[:locale] = params[:locale]
  I18n.locale = params[:locale]
end
render "startsite"
 end
```

what I want is that the language switch will affect on the current page. the render "startsite" is the problem but what could be a good solution to do this?

thanks

Comment: You might want to do a `redirect_to :back`, but maybe test before that the `request.referer` matches a route of your app. If not, redirect to the `root_path` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you need are these snippets:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end
end
```

The first method switches the locale method and the second one always appends the locale param to the request.

edit for comment:

```
# config/routes.rb
scope "/:locale" do
  resources :books
end
```

from rails doc: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: How do I then use that ? Say I have in my view: ` <%= link_to "nl", request.fullpath %> `, where request fullpath is "/fr/boo/bar". How do I replace the "fr" in the url with "nl" ?

Answer (score 0):

You will see in the [I18n Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#localized-views) that you can have localized views thus allowing you to keep that "startsite" by adding a `products/show.de.erb`, `products/show.en-uk.erb` etc.

I do hope `changelocal` is not a action but a `before_filter`? Filters are the most elegant solution for setting the locale and will relieve you of any need to redirect.

Comment: I don't think the `before_filter` is a solution here since @Felix wants an action to change the current locale to another. The `before_filter` should just set `I18n.locale` to the `session[:locale]`, not set the `session[:locale]`

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect to the previous page OR the `root_path` if previous page does not exist:

```
def changelocale
  if Settings.language_supported?(params[:locale])
    session[:locale] = params[:locale]
    I18n.locale = params[:locale]
  end
  redirect_to request.referer.presence || root_path
end
```

But this redirection can lead to 404 not found: if you go to some show page, then hit the delete button, now the `request.referer` is pointing to a show page of a non-existing record. It have to be used with care.

Answer (score 0):

If the locale is part of your URL (and it looks like it is), you can simply change the link in your view to swap to another version of the page.

For example, if your current path is `/en/about`, you could link to `/de/about`, `/fr/about` by taking `request.fullpath` and replacing the current locale with the locale you want to link to.

That way you don't need any filters or redirects.